# Removing escape characters from a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping

How can i remove the escape chars in Python 2.7 and python 3 ?

Example:

```
a = "\u00E7a\u00E7a\u00E7a=http\://\u00E1\u00E9\u00ED\u00F3\u00FA\u00E7/()\=)(){[]}"
decoded =  a.decode('unicode_escape')
print decoded
```

**Result:**

```
çaçaça=http\://áéíóúç/()\=)(){[]}
```

**Expected result**

```
çaçaça=http://áéíóúç/()=)(){[]}
```

EDIT: In order to avoid unnecessary downvotes. using .replace isn't our primary focus since  this problem was raised by a  legacy solution from other teams ( db table with reference data with contains portuguese chars and regular expressions).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a simple *`str.replace`*

```
>>> print decoded.replace('\\', '')
çaçaça=http://áéíóúç/()=)(){[]}
```

The remaining `\` is actually a literal backslash, not an escape sequence.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid using .replace, because this is a reference data , and sometimes it's necessary. not because it's a escape char, but because it belongs to the string.

Comment: @ThalesPereira If the backslash is part of an escape sequence, it will _not_ be replaced.

Comment: @ThalesPereira Try: `v = '\xff'; v.replace('\\', '')` See what happens...

Comment: @COLDSPEED I know, it won't replace, but the problem is sometimes the results from the reference data table contains backslashes that are being replaced by the .replace function. I guess probably for this case I'm going to have to cover every scenario in order to use .replace to not replace everything blindly.

Comment: @ThalesPereira Without any context, you're on your own I'm afraid, I don't know how else I can help you.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm afraid so, the main problem here is that someone a few years ago decided that was a good idea store regular expressions and error messages on the same table.... no ID's, no nothing.... Well, it's going to be a long day. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the unnecessary the escape character in your string, i.e.

```
>>> a = "\u00E7a\u00E7a\u00E7a=http://\u00E1\u00E9\u00ED\u00F3\u00FA\u00E7/()=)(){[]}"
>>> decoded =  a.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> print decoded
çaçaça=http://áéíóúç/()=)(){[]}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid replacements, since sometimes backslashes exists on other strings.